# What are considered in URL Fetch calls limits of Google Apps Scipt

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-query

I use Google Sheets and its Script Editor to handle data of our customers.

Today, I faced this error:

> Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.

Google puts limits of 20000 calls/day for consumer users. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

My question is that what are counted as URL Fetch Calls? Are the `IMPORTRANGE` Function that gets data from another sheets counted in the URL Fetch Calls daily limit? How about the number of internal functions such as: `IF` and `Array formulas`? Are they counted in the daily limit?

Answer (score 0):

This [google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-scripts/MG7T6PHzZTs) might offer insight to your problem:

> Limiting yourself to 800 fetches per script execution will work for
>   one account. However, this 20,000 fetch limit per day applies per-user
>   (i.e. per-login-email), not per-script. If you've got multiple scripts
>   doing URL fetches, they're both eating up the same quota. What you
>   could do to work around this is to check fewer links per script
>   execution, or maybe have another user schedule the script on the other
>   account.